# Boa tradução para "yield management"?

Tags: tradução-inglês

> **Revenue management** ou **Yield Management** é uma técnica de gestão, utilizada para calcular a melhor política de preços (pricing),
>   para otimizar/maximizar os lucros gerados pela venda de um produto ou
>   serviço, baseada em modelos matemáticos de simulação e previsões de
>   tendências de procura por segmento de mercado. Também se pode designar
>   por Revenue Management, é o processo de conhecer, compreender,
>   antecipar e reagir às tendências da procura, para maximizar a
>   receita/Ocupação

Confesso que não apraz uma [gestão sofisticada](https://www.linguee.pt/ingles-portugues/traducao/yield+management.html) ou uma gestão de rendimento.

Talvez

- Otimização de receitas,
- Maximização de vendas,
- Gestão de receitas, ou
- Maximização de receitas?

Comment: Gestão de Receita, Gestão de Ganhos, Gestão de Lucros, Gestão de Retornos, Gestão de Preços, Gestão de Rendimentos, Gestão de Dividendos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na língua inglesa, o verbo `yield` significa "produzir" ou "prover". Consequentemente, o `management` (a gestão) de `yield` é a gestão daquilo que se produz e que se fornece.

Em outras palavras: **yield management** é uma **gestão de oferta**, dentro de uma relação de oferta e demanda.